# Using apt, how to install JDK 7 when JDK 8 is already installed?

Tags: debian, apt, jdk

`java-8-openjdk-amd64` is already installed by default on my Debian testing system (Buster), and I would like to keep it installed.

`openjdk-7-jdk` is not in my testing package list.

According to [its package page](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/openjdk-7-jdk), it’s available on Jessie.
So I added this repository :

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
```

but OpenJDK 7 won’t install:

```
openjdk-7-jdk depends openjdk-7-jre but it is not going to be installed
openjdk-7-jre : depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u151-2.6.11-2~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
openjdk-7-jre : Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not installable
```

I know I can use `update-alternatives` to switch between several JDK versions, but how do I get OpenJDK 7 installed in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

The security repository, which is what you’ve added, isn’t a standalone repository; to use it, you also need to add the corresponding “main” repository:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

This would have allowed you to install OpenJDK 7 in the past; unfortunately, the Jessie package can no longer be installed in a Buster system because it ends up depending on `tzdata-java`, which needs a specific version of `tzdata` which can’t be satisfied without downgrading the Buster version.

There is another way to install OpenJDK 7 on a Buster system: you can install it from `experimental`. Add

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental main
```

to your repositories (and remove the Jessie entries while you’re at it), and run

```
apt install -t experimental openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: I still get `openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u151-2.6.11-2~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed.`
following through the chain of unsatisfied dependancies : 

`tzdata-java : depends: tzdata (= 2017c-0+deb8u1) but 2018c-1 is to be installed`

Comment: Ah yes, that means the Jessie package can’t be used in Buster. There is another solution; see my update.

Comment: apt install -t experimental openjdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate

Comment: @user390436 unfortunately this is one of those answers with a use-by date; two years later, OpenJDK 7 is no longer available in experimental.